# rails test, rails server and others not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

i have been following railstutorial.org in learning rails, and right now, i don't know where my error is from, but rails test isn't testing and rails server isn't coming on

```
C:\Sites\sample_app>rails test
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/bcrypt-3.1.11-x86-mingw32/lib/bcrypt.rb:16:in `require': cannot load such file -- bcrypt_ext (LoadError)
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/bcrypt-3.1.11-x86-mingw32/lib/bcrypt.rb:16:in `rescue in <top (required)>'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/bcrypt-3.1.11-x86-mingw32/lib/bcrypt.rb:12:in `<top (required)>'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.16.1/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:81:in `require'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.16.1/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:81:in `block (2 levels) in require'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.16.1/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:76:in `each'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.16.1/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:76:in `block in require'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.16.1/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:65:in `each'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.16.1/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:65:in `require'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.16.1/lib/bundler.rb:114:in `require'
        from C:/Sites/sample_app/config/application.rb:7:in `<top (required)>'
        from C:/Sites/sample_app/config/environment.rb:2:in `require_relative'
        from C:/Sites/sample_app/config/environment.rb:2:in `<top (required)>'
        from C:/Sites/sample_app/test/test_helper.rb:1:in `require'
        from C:/Sites/sample_app/test/test_helper.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
        from C:/Sites/sample_app/test/controllers/static_pages_controller_test.rb:1:in `require'
        from C:/Sites/sample_app/test/controllers/static_pages_controller_test.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/railties-5.1.4/lib/rails/test_unit/runner.rb:50:in `require'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/railties-5.1.4/lib/rails/test_unit/runner.rb:50:in `block in load_tests'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/railties-5.1.4/lib/rails/test_unit/runner.rb:50:in `each'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/railties-5.1.4/lib/rails/test_unit/runner.rb:50:in `load_tests'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/railties-5.1.4/lib/rails/test_unit/runner.rb:39:in `run'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/railties-5.1.4/lib/rails/commands/test/test_command.rb:38:in `perform'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/thor-0.20.0/lib/thor/command.rb:27:in `run'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/thor-0.20.0/lib/thor/invocation.rb:126:in `invoke_command'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/thor-0.20.0/lib/thor.rb:387:in `dispatch'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/railties-5.1.4/lib/rails/command/base.rb:63:in `perform'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/railties-5.1.4/lib/rails/command.rb:44:in `invoke'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/railties-5.1.4/lib/rails/commands.rb:16:in `<top (required)>'
        from bin/rails:4:in `require'
        from bin/rails:4:in `<main>'
```

here's the error code for the rails s

```
C:\Sites\sample_app>rails s
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/bcrypt-3.1.11-x86-mingw32/lib/bcrypt.rb:16:in `require': cannot load such file -- bcrypt_ext (LoadError)
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/bcrypt-3.1.11-x86-mingw32/lib/bcrypt.rb:16:in `rescue in <top (required)>'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/bcrypt-3.1.11-x86-mingw32/lib/bcrypt.rb:12:in `<top (required)>'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.16.1/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:81:in `require'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.16.1/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:81:in `block (2 levels) in require'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.16.1/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:76:in `each'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.16.1/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:76:in `block in require'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.16.1/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:65:in `each'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.16.1/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:65:in `require'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.16.1/lib/bundler.rb:114:in `require'
        from C:/Sites/sample_app/config/application.rb:7:in `<top (required)>'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/railties-5.1.4/lib/rails/commands/server/server_command.rb:133:in `require'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/railties-5.1.4/lib/rails/commands/server/server_command.rb:133:in `block in perform'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/railties-5.1.4/lib/rails/commands/server/server_command.rb:130:in `tap'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/railties-5.1.4/lib/rails/commands/server/server_command.rb:130:in `perform'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/thor-0.20.0/lib/thor/command.rb:27:in `run'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/thor-0.20.0/lib/thor/invocation.rb:126:in `invoke_command'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/thor-0.20.0/lib/thor.rb:387:in `dispatch'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/railties-5.1.4/lib/rails/command/base.rb:63:in `perform'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/railties-5.1.4/lib/rails/command.rb:44:in `invoke'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/railties-5.1.4/lib/rails/commands.rb:16:in `<top (required)>'
        from bin/rails:4:in `require'
        from bin/rails:4:in `<main>'
```

I don't know where it's from

please if you would like to see any page, just tell me, and i'll upload it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> First of all comment out `# gem bcrypt, '3.1.11'` and run bundle install.After that uninstall the gem with `gem uninstall bcrypt`.Then re-install `gem install bcrypt --platform=ruby`.The important part, un-comment `gem 'bcrypt', '~> 3.1.11', platforms: [:ruby, :x64_mingw, :mingw]` and then bundle install.Thats it.Note the mingw part at the end.This should be the key.

[source](https://github.com/codahale/bcrypt-ruby/issues/149#issuecomment-288713371)

Comment: but without gem 'bcrypt' will i be able to secure password?

Comment: stop. You don't remove gem, read carefully the answer. You uninstall bcrypt and install that rightly for your win platform.

Comment: good, my server on now, but rails test is telling me something else.

Comment: C:\Sites\sample_app>rails test
Migrations are pending. To resolve this issue, run:

        bin/rails db:migrate RAILS_ENV=test'

Comment: run migrations for test env `bin/rails db:migrate RAILS_ENV=test' `

Comment: C:\Sites\sample_app>rails db:migrate RAILS_ENV=test
== 20171229082356 AddIndexToUsersEmail: migrating =============================
-- add_index(:users, :email, {:unique=>true})
rails aborted!
StandardError: An error has occurred, this and all later migrations canceled:

Comment: SQLite3::ConstraintException: UNIQUE constraint failed: users.email: CREATE UNIQUE INDEX "index_users_on_email" ON "users" ("email")
C:/Sites/sample_app/db/migrate/20171229082356_add_index_to_users_email.rb:3:in `change'
bin/rails:4:in `require'
bin/rails:4:in `<main>'

Comment: Caused by:
ActiveRecord::RecordNotUnique: SQLite3::ConstraintException: UNIQUE constraint failed: users.email: CREATE UNIQUE INDEX "index_users_on_email" ON "users" ("email")
C:/Sites/sample_app/db/migrate/20171229082356_add_index_to_users_email.rb:3:in `change'
bin/rails:4:in `require'
bin/rails:4:in `<main>'

Comment: `bin/rails db:drop RAILS_ENV=test` - `bin/rails db:create RAILS_ENV=test` - `bin/rails db:migrate RAILS_ENV=test` - if no result, create new answer with this error and migration file

Comment: please if you don't mind, can i chat you up via any means, i'll love you to mentor me and put me through on some stuffs in rails

Comment: Sorry, but i don't have enough time :( I sugest you to start with some rails tutorials like this for example: https://www.railstutorial.org/book

Answer (score 0):

a) gem uninstall bcrypt-ruby

b) In your gemfile, add

gem 'bcrypt', git: 'https://github.com/codahale/bcrypt-ruby.git', :require => 'bcrypt'

c) bundle install

This works on Windows

Good luck